# Why doesn't "console.log" in Chrome print anything on the localhost page?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, browser, console.log

I'm using Typescript and React on the client side, C# and ASP.Net Core on the server side and JetBrains Rider as IDE. Today suddenly the function "console.log()" doesn't print anything on the development page (localhost) ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjNsA.png)
). But on the other pages it works as usual ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt51n.png)). What could it be?

Comment: Somebody has overriden the logging? It might be build setting that turns it off automatically for staging/production environments and for some reason it's being built with that config. Or maybe somebody mistakenly added it to dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in IDE, I reinstalled it and now the error is gone.